# PDF Realtime down load and conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-realtime-api

Im Looking for a way to use Google Apps Script to Download PDF file and  convert file into Google Sheets.

The reason for this is that website only gives data in PDF form and i cant use Import function to get data for real-time updates

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you will download your pdf files.

Here is simple example how you can convert PDF file from your Google Drive into Googe Document:

```
function pdfToDoc() {  
  var fileBlob = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test.pdf').next().getBlob();
  var resource = {
    title: fileBlob.getName(),
    mimeType: fileBlob.getContentType()
  };
  var options = {
    ocr: true
  };
  var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, fileBlob, options);  
  Logger.log(docFile.alternateLink);  
}
```

To make it work you need to enable Drive API:

[image]

Based on the answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/136948

And as far as I can see there is only DOC as output. Probably you can extract data from DOC and put it into Spreadsheet with script. But it depends on how exactly looks your data.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, the website im talking is “ https://www.transnet.net/TU/Stack/NGQURA%20%20CONTAINER%20%20TERMINAL.pdf “ i want the code to download the file automatically into my google drive to ver 6 to 8 hours and replace the existing file. From there i would like to extract the date to google sheets via google drive.

Comment: Probably there can be a solution based on API of the website transnet.com, I don't know. As a workaround I'd try to install Google Drive on your desktop and use some Python (or Apple Script, or https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/) script to save PDFs from the website to your Google Drive desktop shared folder. This way the PDF files will get on you Google cloud Drive. Then you can process them with the script above (via a time trigger function).

Comment: Probably with https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/ you can download PDFs and upload them on Google Drive cloud directly.